# How to get RDD[Row] (with all values) instead of RDD[Unit] (which is empty)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val sid_df = hiveContext.sql("SELECT a, b, c, d, e FROM my_table")

val new_reformatted_rdd = sid_df.map(row => {
val t = row.getDouble(0)
val f = row.getFloat(1)
val s = row.getShort(2)
val y = row.getString(3).toShort
val originFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy")
val targetFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
val new_date = targetFormat.format(originFormat.parse(row.getString(4)))
})
```

I need a dataframe from new_reformatted_rdd which is an RDD[Unit]. Kindly suggest me how to do it. Thanks

Comment: `RDD[Unit]` is meaningless - what did you intend your RDD to contain? You create many local values (t, f, s, y, new_date) but you never use them, they get "thrown away", perhaps you meant to create a tuple of these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a tuple as the last step of the `map` with the variables you want to keep, otherwise the RDD will be empty. After that you can create a dataframe with the `toDF()` command. Don't forget to do the `import`.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val new_reformatted_rdd = sid_df.map(row => {
  val t = row.getDouble(0)
  val f = row.getFloat(1)
  val s = row.getShort(2)
  val y = row.getString(3).toShort
  val originFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy")
  val targetFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
  val new_date = targetFormat.format(originFormat.parse(row.getString(4)))
  (t, f, s, y, new_date)
}).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5")
```

Comment: Yes. This works. Thanks. But, As i have `spark 1.6` `SparkSession` is not available. So after creating a tuple, I am Converting `new_reformatted_rdd` which is an `RDD[(Double, Float, Short, Short, String)] to RDD[Row]` by `val result_rdd = new_reformatted_rdd.map(p => Row(p._1, p._2, p._3, p._4, p._5))`. And then I can do `createDataframe(RDD[Row]), schema)` which works fine.